# How to Select an Item with Multiple Hashtags

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables in my database.

Table `tags` consists of: `tag_id`, `tag_name`

Table `person` consists of: `person_id`, `person_name`, etc

Table `maintag` consists of: `main_tag_id`, `tag_id`, `person_id`

For example, there is someone named Benny that has tags `new york`, `fat` and `smart`. Every time I search like this:

```
SELECT p.person_name, p.gpa, p.phone_number FROM person p
LEFT JOIN maintag mg ON mg.person_id = p.person_id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.tag_id = mg.tag_id
WHERE t.tag_name LIKE '%fat%' AND t.tag_name LIKE '%smart%'
```

It will return 0. What should my query look like when I want to select an item with multiple tags?

I've read [MySQL - select all items with multiple hashtags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460215/mysql-select-all-items-with-multiple-hashtags) and that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: What does it return if you take out the WHERE statement?

Comment: It just return all the tables combined. And for person that doesn't has tags, it will contain "NULL" in tag_name field

Comment: Try using `OR` instead of `AND` in your condition. Do you also received an error? Try doing some error reporting.

Comment: If I use or, then if I search multiple tags for example ("fat", "smart", "books"), it will return Benny. Whereas Benny doesn't belong to "books"

Comment: Looks good to me after assigning the `person` column as `p`. Any update?

Comment: I think there is no more error. But still doesn't select the data as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WHERE clause will never work because a single tag row will never be both fat and smart. You'll need to get two different tags.
You didn't provide data but I think you are trying for this:

```
tags:
1 = fat
2 = thin
3 = smart
4 = dumb

person
1 = jack
2 = benny
```

So if benny is fat and smart, maintag has two rows:

```
maintag_id = 1   person_id = 2  tag_id = 1  (means benny is fat)
maintag_id = 2   person_id = 2  tag_id = 3  (means benny is smart)
```

You would select all the fat smart people like this:

```
SELECT p.person_name, p.gpa, p.phone_number FROM person p
LEFT JOIN maintag mg1 ON mg1.person_id = p.person_id
LEFT JOIN maintag mg2 ON mg2.person_id = p.person_id
LEFT JOIN tags t1 ON t1.tag_id = mg1.tag_id
LEFT JOIN tags t2 ON t2.tag_id = mg2.tag_id
WHERE t1.tag_name LIKE '%fat%' AND t2.tag_name LIKE '%smart%'
```